# scala Range for Long

Tags: list, scala, append, range, out-of-memory

I'm new to the Scala language.

I need Range for Long type.

I need a List of [1, 2, 3 ... 10000000] with step 1. If I use until/to I get an error because of using Long instead of Int.

I try to write simple function which expects a start, an end and and an empty List and generates a List of [start .. end].

Here is my function:

```
def range_l(start : Long, end : Long, list : List[Long]) : List[Long] = {
    if (start == end){
        val add_to_list = start :: list
        return add_to_list
    }
    else {
        val add_to_list = start :: list
        range_l(start + 1, end, add_to_list)
    }
}
```

If I call it like: `range_l(1L, 1000000L, List())` i get `OutOfMemory` error in the following line: `add_to_list = start :: list`

What can you advice me? How can I get `Range[Long]` or how can I optimize the function. How can I avoid OutOfMemory?

Thank you.

Comment: Ranges generally do not need to be materialized. Try `1.to(Int.MaxValue)` on the REPL and look at the resulting type. Feel free to then [look at the Scala source](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range$$Inclusive.html) for such type :)

Comment: You are talking about `Range`, but your function returns `List` it is different types in scala. If you want `List[Long]`, you can `List.range(0L, 10)`

Comment: Why do you need such a range? It's pretty easy to get one (see paradigmatic's answer), but using it is often impractical. There might be better solutions to your problem. Also, what is your error? `1 to 10000000` doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 16):

You can create such a range by using the following syntax:

```
val range = 1L to 10000000L
```

The 'L' is mandatory to inform the compiler that the litterals are longs and not ints.

You can then use almost all `List` methods on the instance `range`. It should not fill you memory because the intermediate values are generated when needed. The range can be passed to any method expecting a `Traversable[Long]`, a `Seq[Long]`, an `Iterable[Long]`, etc.

However, if you really need a `List` just call `range.toList` (and increase the heap size to accommodate all the list elements)...

Comment: although `1L to 10000000000L` produces an IllegalArgumentException: "seqs cannot contain more than Int.MaxValue elements"

Comment: @DNA Yes indeed, in that case you can use streams or your own iterator. Standard lib collections have a size method which must return an Int... If you have special needs, you should use a special collection.

Answer (score 9):

You probably do not need a range. I would take a Stream and iterate over it.

```
def stream(i: Long = 1): Stream[Long] = i #:: stream(i + 1)
```

produces an infinit Stream where the difference between the elements is 1. Because Stream is a lazy collection you will not gett any Errors. To iterate over 10000000 elements you simply use the following:

```
val range = stream take 10000000
for (i <- range) {
  ...
}
```

`take 10000000` will return a `Stream` with size 10000000. Because `Stream` is an `Iterable` you can pass it to a for comprehansion.

Answer (score 9):

You can instead use [NumericRange[Long]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange) from the standard library.

Comment: For Long numbers it will also throw "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than Int.MaxValue elements." error message.