# How Scala make a series for type Long?

Tags: scala

it is ok when  `2 to 9999`
but it is wrong when `2l to 9999999999l`  ,where l stands for type Long.

Comment: @m-z No, it doesn't have to be capitalized. Either works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala Range for Long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511171/scala-range-for-long)

Comment: The size of your range is your problem, not the content being Longs.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it is a `Range` of `Long` values, the number of elements it contains is still limited to `Int.MaxValue`.

From the [Standard Library docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Range):

> Ranges that contain more than Int.MaxValue elements can be created,
>   but these overfull ranges have only limited capabilities. Any method
>   that could require a collection of over Int.MaxValue length to be
>   created, or could be asked to index beyond Int.MaxValue elements will
>   throw an exception. Overfull ranges can safely be reduced in size by
>   changing the step size (e.g. by 3) or taking/dropping elements.

If you need a range of more than `Int.MaxValue` elements, you might consider using a `Stream`.

```
val longRange = Stream.iterate[Long](2)(_+1).takeWhile(_ < 9999999999L)
```