# Collatz - maximum number of steps and the corresponding number

Tags: scala, list, max, collatz

I am trying to write a Scala function that takes an upper bound as argument and calculates the steps for the numbers in a range from 1 up to this bound. It had to return the maximum number of steps and the corresponding number that needs that many steps. (as a pair - first element is the number of steps and second is the corresponding index)

I already have created a function called "collatz" which computes the number of steps. I am very new with Scala and I am a bit stuck because of the limitations. Here's how I thought to start the function:

```
def max(x:Int):Int = {
  for (i<-(1 to x).toList) yield collatz(i)
```

the way I think to solve this problem is to: 1. iterate through the range and apply collatz to all elements while putting them in a new list which stores the number of steps. 2. find the maximum of the new list by using List.max 3. Use List.IndexOf to find the index. However, I'm really stuck since I don't know how to do this without using var (and only using val). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def collatzMax(n: Long): (Long, Long) = {
  require(n > 0, "Collatz function is not defined for n <= 0")

  def collatz(n: Long, steps: Long): Long = n match {
    case n if (n <= 1)     => steps
    case n if (n % 2 == 0) => collatz(n / 2, steps + 1)
    case n if (n % 2 == 1) => collatz(3 * n + 1, steps + 1)
  }

  def loop(n: Long, current: Long, acc: List[(Long, Long)]): List[(Long, Long)] = 
    if (current > n) acc
    else {
      loop(n, current + 1, collatz(current, 0) -> current :: acc)
    }

  loop(n, 1, Nil).sortBy(-_._1).head
}
```

Example:

```
collatzMax(12)
result: (Long, Long) = (19,9) // 19 steps for collatz(9)
```

Using for:

```
def collatzMax(n: Long) = 
  (for(i <- 1L to n) yield collatz(i) -> i).sortBy(-_._1).head
```

Or(continuing your idea):

```
def maximum(x: Long): (Long, Long) = {
  val lst = for (i <- 1L to x) yield collatz(i) 
  val maxValue = lst.max
  (maxValue, lst.indexOf(maxValue) + 1)
}
```

Comment: I haven't yet covered some of the things in your soultion so I am trying to get it by only using for loop, .toList, List.max and indexOf. I can show you how I solved the first part (the collatz function)

Comment: `code` def collatz(n: Long): Long = {
  val count=1
  if (n==1) {
  count
} else if (n%2==1) {
    val count2=collatz(n*3+1)+1
    count2
  }
   else {
     val count3=collatz(n/2) +1 
     count3
   }
}
  `code`

Comment: I added the solution using  a `for` loop

Comment: I cannot use sortBy either, can you tell me why my code is not working? (despite being inefficient) I just really need to use the most basic syntax

Comment: `code` 
def maximum(x:Long):Long = { 
   for (i<-1 to x) {
     val maxList=collatz(i).toList
}
val maxValue=maxList.max
val index=maxList.indexOf(maxValue)
}
val p=(maxValue,index)  `code`

Comment: see the updated response. also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511171/scala-range-for-long . Your syntax was wrong

Comment: Hmm, I see. I understand the way you did it but there's only one argument for the collatz function, can I remove the 0 and run it with just the index?

Comment: Sure, your implementation of `collatz` accepts only the index

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the help, I finally understand it!!

Comment: I think this: `case n if (n % 2 == 1)` is unnecessary. It's already covered by the prior "even" check so you should just consider it the default `case _`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(1 to x).map(collatz).maxBy(_._2)._1
```

Comment: `code`
    def maximum(x:Long):Long = { for (i<-1 to x) {
     val maxList=collatz(i).toList
}
val maxValue=maxList.max
val index=maxList.indexOf(maxValue)
}
val p=(maxValue,index) `code`  
Why doesn't this work? How exactly is return treated as in scala?

Comment: @JamesT For starters, that code doesn't compile. What is `collatz(i).toList` supposed to do? doesn't the `collatz` function return `Int`? What is the type of `collatz`? We need to see either compilable code or the compilation error.